# Compare date in JSTL doesn't work as expected

Tags: jsp, datetime, comparison, jstl

With the following JSTL

(The date input comes from a `messages.properties` file in the given pattern)

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
Current: ${now}<br/>

<c:catch>
    <fmt:parseDate value="${tickerBegin}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" var="tickerBeginDate" />
    <fmt:parseDate value="${tickerEnd}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" var="tickerEndDate" />
</c:catch>
${tickerBegin} parsed to ${tickerBeginDate}<br/>
${tickerEnd} parsed to ${tickerEndDate}<br/>

${tickerEndDate ge nowDate}<br/>
${tickerEndDate.time ge nowDate.time}<br/>
```

I receive this output:

```
Current: Thu Jun 30 17:05:10 CEST 2016
2016-06-30 14:00:00 parsed to Thu Jun 30 14:00:00 CEST 2016
2017-02-04 03:32:12 parsed to Sat Feb 04 03:32:12 CET 2017
false
false
```

Why do none of those comparisons work as expected? Obviously, any date in 2017 must be larger than any date in 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `nowDate` is never defined in your code. Try

```
${tickerEndDate ge now}<br/>
${tickerEndDate.time ge now.time}<br/>
```

Comment: Well I guess thats what you call being routine blinded... Thanks